# Push creates new remote heads! (did you forget to merge? use push -f to force)

Tags: mercurial

Ok I've had a little google and can't find a solution as i've stumbled across the same message but different ways in which people have got it. I'm new to mecurial and want to make sure i'm doing this correctly.

So i'm getting the error message as above. I have a dev site and a live site and i'm trying to push the code to codebase.

However yesterday I accidentally did `hg add` which added all the media which i didn't want to do. I did revert after to remove all the media files from codebase, by then committing and push the changes. So today i've been making changes to the CSS file and a few templates. I've gone to commit my changes and push them but when i run `hg push` I get the error above.

I've run hg log and there are only 6 commits as it's a clean/new branch/project. Any help would be much appreciated and I apologize if i've not explained anything correctly!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This isn't an "error" message; it's a totally normal situation.  That message is saying "hey, other people pushed new work to that repository while you were doing your work, you should probably integrate theirs into your so they don't have to integrate yours into theirs?"

So first do a:

```
hg pull
```

and then a:

```
hg merge
```

Incidentally the `revert` you did if you actually used the `hg revert` command didn't remove those files from history, so your history is probably pretty big.

Consider reading the first few chapters of the [Mercurial book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/index.html) it covers these situations quite well.

Comment: A legitimate situation is if you need to create a patch based on a very specific older version.   You can then later merge that patch into your main dev branch.

Comment: @AnthonyVO And what's the solution in this situation? I have to patch an old release. hg push -f ?

Comment: @TheincredibleJan, 1. Get the release/version you NEED to patch, 2. Make and commit the changes (creating a new head if required), 3. Merge the changes back into the main branch.  Repeat until you no longer need to maintain the older release.  Your objective is to limit the scope of any patches.  Very often, the users prefer to upgrade all the way to a new release instead of the patch I just created for them.

Comment: A pull then merge doesn't necessarily fix the situation.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to **cancel your conflicting changes**

```
hg outgoing
```

You should see lines containing your commited/conflicting changes which are not pushed. Search for the changeset revision. Here **64**

```
searching for changes
changeset:   64:1830948c246e
```

Then

```
hg strip 64
```

Answer (score 19):

This worked for me.

```
hg push -f
```

For more command, try

```
hg help push
```

Comment: Adding the "force" flag isn't really a "solution" any more than "creates new remote head" is an error..

Comment: This is a _solution_, but only if you know what you are doing. For instance when you close a branch and want to restart the branch (without merge, overriding any changes of the closed branch, but with the same name), then `--force` is probably what you want. The key here is to _know what you are doing_, otherwise don't use `--force` (which should be your default).

Comment: This is NOT a solution?! I have to patch an old release and this message prevents a push. If this is not an error why it don't just do what I want without getting on my nerves? What should I do instead of this?

Answer (score 1):

On TortoiseHg you can do this:

1 => Commit your files

2 => Go do your new branch, where you want to push your code

3 => On this branch, run Merge with develop

4 => Push your code whithout errors!

Comment: "Merge with develop"? What "develop"? Do you mean "default"? I can't merge. I have to leave any other old code untouched and only want do push my changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Workbench to push the changes you can try the Detect outgoing changes first, See the attached Image

[image]

This will give you info on what is you are going to push.
My issue was, i had an old `draft` pending to be pushed. I was able to continue with the push once i have done `strip` on the old draft.

Comment: You can also simply filter the repository to `draft()` (show the revisions in 'draft' state). (This is not 100% reliable, if you have done something fancy like changing the revision state or pulled/pushed to a different repository, but under normal circumstances it will work.)