# Really needed two heads in two distinguished branches

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

We have this situation on TortoiseHg and Bitbucket where it is stored the shared repository:

[image]
The merge between the job of dev1 and dev2 shall be done by dev1; but dev1 cannot see the job of dev2 because the latest cannot push his job on the bitbucket repository since he is stopped by HG with this reason "abort: push creates new remote head 2221daef6518 on branch 'Federico Development'"

I fear that problem has been originated by one commit by dev2, the one that is marked in the picture with the 2 red circles: he committed on federico branch locally while federico was also working and committing on the same branch.

Whatever was the original cause of the problem, we would like to let the dev2 to push to the shared repository his work as a different branch head with respect to dev1 so that dev1 can pull the dev2 job and merge the two heads. Is it possible any workaround to get this result?

Secondarily, we would like to understand the origin of the problem for a better understanding and to prevent it in the future:

1. is it true that the problem has been originated by the commit of dev2 ono dev1 branch?
2. why HG still stops even if after that unlucky commit dev2 has changed the branch with a second commit?
3. is there any way to assign to every user a specific branch or, in other words, to deny the commit access on a specific branch to some users?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push creates new remote heads! (did you forget to merge? use push -f to force)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724300/push-creates-new-remote-heads-did-you-forget-to-merge-use-push-f-to-force)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial by default does not allow multiple heads on one branch to be pushed to server. In you case, dev2 created a new commit on dev1 branch and that created a new head.

Now answering your questions one by one:

1. Yes, the problem orignated because dev2 created a new commit on dev1 branch which resulted in dev1 branch having multiple heads.
2. Commits in mercurial are part of the commit information. So the first commit which dev2 did is still on dev1 branch even after dev2 created a new commit on new branch.
3. Yes, you can write a precommit hook to achieve that.

Following is a way you can solve this problem for now:

dev2 can push using the extra head using `--force` flag. This will push the new head to the server. This way the commits will be exchanged but you will end up with multiple heads on dev1 branch which you will need to resolve by merging or some other way.

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer, I  was worried that --force option could have mixed up the two heads code. What could happen instead if dev2 before pushing to the server makes a pull and then a push? I read a similar suggestion in atlassian community possibly also a pull+rebase, but not sure that the final effect is the same: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Did-a-commit-before-I-did-a-pull/qaq-p/352525

Comment: @fede72bari you should merge, not rebase. rebasing changsets which have been made by different people and are public will be much more confusing. A merge is the standard method.

Comment: thank you but i need to merge on the client of the other developer passing through the shared repository. I will try the option suggested in the answer by Pulkit Goyal.